Updating Android Gradle plugin above 3.2
I am trying to create the sign in keys for my flutter app by running build\Generate signed bundle or apk but I can't since I need to have android gradle plugin 3.2.0 or above. So I tried updating my Android Gradle plugin with
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}

in my app\build.gradle file. But when I run flutter build apk this error pops up:
"[!] Your app is using an unsupported Gradle project. To fix this problem, create a new project by running flutter create -t app <app-directory> and then move the dart code, assets and pubspec.yaml to the new project."
I tried multiple ways of surpassing the andoird plugin version requirements and updating it but nothing is working.
